# Is it possible to use an AVAudioUnit from a AUv3 extension in a AudioKit chain?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiokit, auv3

I am trying to insert an AUv3 audio unit into the AudioKit chain.
Here is my code:

```
    AVAudioUnit.instantiate(with: componentDescription, options: []) { (unit, error) in

        guard let audioUnit = unit as? AVAudioUnitMIDIInstrument else {return}

        let node = AKAudioUnitInstrument(audioUnit: audioUnit)

        self.mixer.connect(input: node)
```

The execution just hangs on the `connect` method without any errors.

Am I doing something wrong or does AudioKit not support AUv3 yet?

I am using AudioKit/Core (4.9.3)

Comment: All of the AudioKit nodes are AUv3 themselves, but it seems like you're not really using any complete nodes, just the AKAudioUnitInstrument. Perhaps you can look at one of the oscillator or effect nodes and use it as a model for your own stuff?

Comment: What I tried to do here is to initialize a third-party Audio Unit(not mine, and not from AudioKit) and then having an initialized AVAudioUnit instance, I wanted to turn it into a AudioKit node, so I could use it in the AK chain.